# Magento Card Payments with Paypal Pro Giving Error

Tags: php, magento, paypal

When completing a card purchase I get the following error:

There was an error processing your order. Please contact us or try again later.

The Magento error log is here:

```
exception 'Exception' with message 'Notice: Array to string conversion  in /home/luluinth/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php on line 1060' in /home/luluinth/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Core/functions.php:247
    Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: mageCoreErrorHandler(8, 'Array to string...', '/home/luluinth/...', 1060, Array)
#1 /home/luluinth/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php(1060): sprintf('PayPal NVP gate...', Array, '4f0c10ba893f2', '72.0')
#2 /home/luluinth/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php(1008): Mage_Paypal_Model_Api_Nvp->_handleCallErrors(Array)
#3 /home/luluinth/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php(659): Mage_Paypal_Model_Api_Nvp->call('DoDirectPayment', Array)
#4 /home/luluinth/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Direct.php(343): Mage_Paypal_Model_Api_Nvp->callDoDirectPayment()
#5 /home/luluinth/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Direct.php(202): Mage_Paypal_Model_Direct->_placeOrder(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment), '12')
#6 /home/luluinth/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(443): Mage_Paypal_Model_Direct->capture(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment), '12')
#7 /home/luluinth/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php(385): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->capture(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice))
#8 /home/luluinth/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(608): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice->capture()
#9 /home/luluinth/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(410): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->_invoice()
#10 /home/luluinth/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(348): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->capture(NULL)
#11 /home/luluinth/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(886): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->place()
#12 /home/luluinth/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(1104): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->_placePayment()
#13 [internal function]: Mage_Sales_Model_Order->place()
#14 /home/luluinth/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(105): call_user_func(Array)
#15 /home/luluinth/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(159): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->_runCallbacks()
#16 /home/luluinth/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(189): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->save()
#17 /home/luluinth/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(249): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitOrder()
#18 /home/luluinth/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php(785): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
#19 /home/luluinth/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(579): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->saveOrder()
#20 /home/luluinth/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->saveOrderAction()
#21 /home/luluinth/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveOrder')
#22 /home/luluinth/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#23 /home/luluinth/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#24 /home/luluinth/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#25 /home/luluinth/public_html/index.php(98): Mage::run('', 'store')
#26 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to cast $value as a string for the comparison, but $value is an array. If $value has some kind of value you need in it (perhaps it's nested inside an array) for the comparison, then you must process it so that it is not array.

Go to that nvp.php file and do this before the if statement.

var_dump($value); die;

Or

Mage::log($value); // Check var/log/system.log with logging enabled

And just examine how the data is structured in $value. Make it into a string variable.

*Here $value is a variable you can put the variable from the line number that exception is generated*.

Check this and let me know if it works.